# Extract the largest color blob opencv4android

Tags: android, image-processing

I need help to extract the largest color blob like in this site [bytefish.de](http://bytefish.de/blog/extracting_contours_with_opencv/)

i have successfully get the largest color blob but i dont know how to extract it and get it to a new bitmap.

here is my code :

```
            Mat matImage = new Mat(b.getHeight(), b.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
            Bitmap myBitmap32 = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

            Utils.bitmapToMat(myBitmap32, matImage);

            Mat hsv = new Mat();
            Imgproc.cvtColor(matImage, hsv, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);

            Scalar lowerThreshold = new Scalar(0, 0.23 * 255, 50); // brown/skin color sana – lower hsv values
            Scalar upperThreshold = new Scalar(50, 0.68 * 255, 255); // brown/skin color sana  – higher hsv values
            Mat segmentedImage = new Mat();

            Core.inRange(hsv, lowerThreshold, upperThreshold, segmentedImage);

            Mat dilatedMat = new Mat();

            Imgproc.dilate(segmentedImage, dilatedMat, new Mat());


            List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
            Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
            Imgproc.findContours(dilatedMat, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

            double maxVal = 0;
            int maxValIdx = 0;
            for (int contourIdx = 0; contourIdx < contours.size(); contourIdx++)
            {
                double contourArea = Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(contourIdx));
                if (maxVal < contourArea)
                {
                    maxVal = contourArea;
                    maxValIdx = contourIdx;
                }
            }

            Imgproc.drawContours(matImage, contours, maxValIdx, new Scalar(0,255,0), -1);


            final Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(matImage.cols(), matImage.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Utils.matToBitmap(matImage, resultBitmap);`
```

[here is my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZblHB.png)

Comment: Can you upload your result ? it will give better clarity where you went wrong...

Comment: @JeruLuke i uploaded it. do you know how to crop the hand?

Comment: So you have obtained the contour of your hand. Now draw **that** contour on a plain background. By plain background , I mean a uniformly colored background.

Comment: @JeruLuke i did something like this ` Mat emptyMat = new Mat();
                emptyMat.setTo(new Scalar(255,255,255));` then i set that emptyMat to the drawContour `Imgproc.drawContours(emptyMat, contours, maxValIdx, new Scalar(0,255,0), 2);` then i converted the emptyMat to bitmap and i getting some RuntimeException

Comment: Try `new Mat::zeros(src.size(),CV_8UC3)`

Comment: @PSchn but idont have ARGB mat..